# Track a buyers path Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

is there anyway within Google Analytics to track a buyers path to purchase. For example, for each transaction can the pages be tracked prior to the final purchase (e.g. organic search > homepage > widgets > red widgets > purchase)?

Interested  to read if there's anyway I can get to this information, as it would be incredibly useful. I'm sure it's there, it's just finding it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Reverse Goal Path section in GA shows this information.

Conversions > Goals > Reverse Goal Path

Comment: Hi thank you for the response but I'd like to track the path for actual sales (seem to appear in 'e commerce' section). Is there a way I can do this using goals or is this something I can filter through the ecommerce section?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up destination goals to your purchase receipt/thankyou pages and create funnels with different steps you have your users take. For example:

Home page>
Product page>
Cart page>
Purchase confirmation/receipt (goal)

you can see your configured funnel data from the Conversions>Goals>Funnel Visualization

[image: Goal funnel visualization]

Goals and funnels can get pretty complex depending on your environment.
Though I found the [LunaMetrics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/10/21/goals-funnels-confusion-google-analytics/) blog to be very helpful in my setup.

Your question is vague on details but this should point you in the right direction.